# Function pointer without specifiying argument and return type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass the name of a method as a string. To accomplish this i created below class:

```
public static class ActionExtension
{
    public static string GetName(this Func<int, Object> funcPtr)
    {
        return funcPtr.Method.Name;
    }

    .......
}
```

For using i do this:

```
Func<int, Object> mailClickActionName = EmailView;    // sinature is => public ActionResult EmailView(int id)
Func<int, int, Object> apiFunc = new MailsController().Trashes;    // sinature is => public SomeClass Trashes()

string ItemAnchorAddress = mailClickActionName.GetName();
```

The problem is i have lots of methods (Actions to be specific) that have different number of arguments and may not return any value. In the **ActionExtension** class i have lots of copied methods that their implementation are equal but their signature is different. Complete ActionExtension class is here:

```
public static class ActionExtension
{
    // Num #1
    public static string GetName(this Func<int, Object> funcPtr)
    {
        return funcPtr.Method.Name;
    }
    public static string GetName(this Func<Object> funcPtr)
    {
        // Exactly the same as #1
    }    
    public static string GetName(this Action<Object> funcPtr)
    {
        // Exactly the same as #1
    }
    public static string GetName(this Func<Object, Object, Object> funcPtr)
    {
        // Exactly the same as #1
    }

    // #2
    public static string GetNameWithController(this Func<int, Object> funcPtr)
    {
        string controller = funcPtr.Target.GetType().Name;
        return controller.Substring(0, controller.LastIndexOf("Controller")) + "/" + funcPtr.Method.Name + "/";
    }
    public static string GetNameWithController(this Func<int, int, Object> funcPtr)
    {
        // Exactly the same as #2
    }

    public static string GetNameWithController(this Func<Object> funcPtr)
    {
        // Exactly the same as #2
    }
    public static string GetNameWithController(this Func<Object, Object> funcPtr)
    {
        // Exactly the same as #2
    }
    public static string GetNameWithController(this Action<Object> funcPtr)
    {
        // Exactly the same as #2
    }

    public static string GetNameWithController(this Func<Object, Object, Object> funcPtr)
    {
        // Exactly the same as #2            
    }
}
```

How can i sum of all methods to just #1 and #2? Thanks.

Comment: is `nameof(EmailView)` / `nameof(MailsController.Trashes)` a possibility? 'cos that's a lot simpler, but retains the safety of not being a magic string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Delegate` class, which is a "parent" of all delegates:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static string GetName(this Delegate funcPtr) {
        return funcPtr.Method.Name;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it for all delegates:

```
static void Main() {
    Action test = Test;
    var name = test.GetName();
    name = ((Action<int>)Test2).GetName();            
}

public static void Test() {}
public static void Test2(int arg) { }
```

Comment: you made my life easy. Thanks.